# lca calculation with brightway '2.5'

Tags: brightway, pyfilesystem

I am trying to calculate montecarlo results with the development version of brightway. From a newly created environment I first tried with the versions I had installed (bw2calc 2.0.dev ; bw2data 4.0.dev ; fs 2.4.11). (installing fs using the conda-forge channel). when I run

```
lca.lci()
```

I get an AttributeError : 'ReadZipFS' object has no attribute 'filter_by_attribute'

does it need a specific version of the fs package?

I am running the calculation on a mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the development release of `bw2data`, should be fixed within 6 hours of this answer.